# underscore.js unbind

Tags: javascript, raphael, backbone.js, underscore.js

I would love to unbind this:

```
$("body").mousemove(_.bind(this.mousemove, this));
```

Due to a complicated mix between backbone.js and raphael.js I need to do the bind via underscore.js:

```
var NodeView = Backbone.View.extend({

        dx: 0,
        dy: 0,

        click: function(event){
            alert('hello')
        },
        mousedown: function(event){
            this.dx = event.pageX - this.el.attr('x');
            this.dy = event.pageY - this.el.attr('y');
            this.el.attr({fill: "#0099FF"});

            $("body").mousemove(_.bind(this.mousemove, this));
        },
        mousemove: function(event){
            this.el.attr({  x: event.pageX - this.dx,
                            y: event.pageY - this.dy});
        },
        mouseup: function(event){
            this.el.attr({fill: "#EEEEEE"});
            $("body").mousemove(_.bind(this.mousenotmove, this));
        },

        render: function(){
            this.el = canvas.rect(this.model.get('xPos'), this.model.get('yPos'), 50, 50).attr({
                fill:   "#EEEEEE",
                stroke: "none",
                cursor: "move"
            });

            $(this.el.node).mousedown(_.bind(this.mousedown, this));
            $(this.el.node).mouseup(_.bind(this.mouseup, this));

            return this;
        }
    });
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Is that also jQuery code mixed in there?

Comment: Also, it's extremely unlikely for the Underscore "bind" to be an issue here.  It looks like what you need to do is unbind event handlers, which has nothing (directly) to do with what the Underscore "bind" is being used for.  All it ("_.bind()") does is provide functions with a pre-bound `this` value.

Comment: Yes there is also jQuery mixed in. The problem is that I have a Backbone view and a Raphäel object and that I need to update the Backbone model attached to the view. And I can't do that if I bind the events directly to the Raphäel object ...

Comment: $("body").unbind("mousemove"); worked. Can I give you some stackoverflow points?

Comment: @ichbinadrian you can answer your own question if you like, and then I can vote for you :-)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Thanks to @Pointy (thank you :D):

The solution is a simple as: $("body").unbind("mousemove");

See comments in first post.